# how to implement voice call using bluetooth in and only in java?

Tags: java, api, mobile, bluetooth, pbx

I know this question is beyond the scope of SO , i have searched  it every where if anyone has this code in **java** or anyone knows where it is on the web then tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a lot of phone-specific knowledge, but here are good sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750358/android-java-connect-to-a-paired-bluetooth-device-and-routing-audio-voice-cal

[Java app to dial a phone](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t494290-using-a-java-application-to-dial-a-mobile-cell-phone-via-bluetooth.html)